# How to get selected values to jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

```
foreach($data as $row)
{
    $output .= '
    <tr>
      <td class="col-xs-3">'.$row->policyno.'</td>
    <td class="col-xs-3">'.$row->q_tree.'</td>
    <td class="col-xs-3">'.$row->Tt_tree.'</td>
    <td class="col-xs-3"> 
      <input id="checkbox" style="margin-left:20px" value='.$row->policyno.' type="checkbox" name="plcdata[]" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    ';
}
```

I use this loop to view the data inside a table and pass to view page using Ajax and I have added a checkbox as an input for select rows in the table. My question is how to get selected rows using javascript `name="plcdata[]` array of checkbox input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will get all the checked lines and store them in an array:

```
let values = [];
$("#checkbox").each(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
         values.push($(this).parent().parent()); //first parent is td, it parent is tr
    }
});
```

Comment: I am really surprised since there is no jQuery tag anywhere in the question and still the answer is accepted!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch all the checkboxes selected by using this:

```
<input id="UNIQUE_ID" style="margin-left:20px" value='.$row->policyno.' type="checkbox" name="plcdata[]" class="plcdata"/>

var policyno = [];
var checkedBoxes = $('.plcdata:checked');
    $.each(checkedBoxes, function () {
    policyno.push(value);
})
```

You should also use unique id for all checkbox, if you want to add id else you can remove it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div><input type="checkbox" value="4" class="chk"> Value 4</div>
```

Value 5

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#getValue').on('click', function(){
        // Declare a checkbox array
        var chkArray = [];
        
        // Look for all checkboxes that have a specific class and was checked
        $(".chk:checked").each(function() {
            chkArray.push($(this).val());
        });
        
        // Join the array separated by the comma
        var selected;
        selected = chkArray.join(',') ;
        
        // Check if there are selected checkboxes
        if(selected.length > 0){
            alert("Selected checkboxes value: " + selected); 
        }else{
            alert("Please select at least one checkbox."); 
        }
    });
});
```

```
this was found on another web page. this is work properly. that was solved my problem.
```